# OpenMDAO genetic algorithm not running in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm, openmdao

I am setting up an optimisation in openMDAO with the SimpleGADriver, where the points in a generation are executed in parallel.

As I am new to openMDAO and relatively new to parallel computing, I started experimenting with the simple example in the openMDAO documentation: https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/drivers/genetic_algorithm.html#running-a-ga-in-parallel

However, when I run this example script I suspect it is not executing any tasks in parallel.

I tried printing debug messages using `prob.driver.options['debug_print'] = ['objs']`, but it seems the optimisation is only being executed on a single rank (rank0), whereas I would expect it to be performed on more than one after setting `prob.driver.options['run_parallel'] = True` :

```
Driver debug print for iter coord: rank0:SimpleGA|528
-----------------------------------------------------
Objectives
{'comp.f': array([0.49454471])}
```

Additionally, I increased the computational time of each Branin function evaluation by forcing it to wait with a `time.sleep()` command before returning the output. In that way the optimisation should definitely benefit from parallellisation, and I'd expect it to run a lot faster when the `'run_parallel'` option is set to `True`. However, the elapsed time is approximately the same when the parallel option is disabled.

I am using python 3.9 and openmdao v3.25 on a Windows 10 PC, and I have MPI and mpi4py installed in my conda environment.

I have checked out similar threads on Stack Overflow but I haven't found a solution yet.
Am I missing something here? Any help or advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question! The first clarifying question I have is: are you running the script with mpirun? So it'd be something like `mpirun -n 4 python <script_name>` in a terminal. That's necessary for the script to run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JohnJasa, I tried running the code from the terminal with `mpiexec -n 4 python <openmdao_test.py>` but indeed I get the same error as mentioned in the answer from @swryan. It seems windows is not the way to go when one tries to perform parallel processing with openmdao...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to install `mpi` and `mpi4py` to your `conda` environment.  You also need an underlying MPI implementation (e.g. mpich, OpenMPI or [Microsoft MPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/microsoft-mpi)). OpenMDAO also requires [PETSc](https://petsc.org/) to run in parallel under MPI.

For example, I tried running the GA example in parallel without having installed PETSc and I got the following error:

```
(OM) PS D:\OpenMDAO> mpiexec -n 4 python .\ga.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OpenMDAO\ga.py", line 19, in <module>
    prob.setup()
  File "C:\Users\swryan\miniconda3\envs\OM\Lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 924, in setup
    raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Attempting to run in parallel under MPI but "
ValueError: Problem ga: Attempting to run in parallel under MPI but PETScVector could not be imported.
```

Installing PETSc on windows can be difficult as documented [here](https://petsc.org/main/install/windows) on the PETSc web site.

The consensus of OpenMDAO users who operate on Windows seems to be that the best solution is to use [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) (WSL2) to give you a Linux environment that works pretty seamlessly with Windows, especially with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

In the Linux environment it is a simple matter to `conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py petsc4py` or `conda install -c conda-forge openmpi mpi4py petsc4py`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I understand now why it didn't work. I was hoping the solution would be a bit easier, though. My program will probably be reused by others (also on windows) in the future, and I wouldn't want them to go through such a painful installation procedure. I will investigate alternative ways to perform optimisation in my framework.